# How do you go through two int arrays and sum their values if they exist

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to create a method that I can send two arrays (that will be containing ints). These arrays wont necessarily be equally long. for example first array could have an index of 15 while the second array has an index of 12. in that case I want to add array1 and array2 for the first 12 then just get the value of array1 for the last 3.

I thought something like this:

```
int[] ArrTotal(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
        int[] total = new int[15];

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (array1[i] != null && array2[i] != null)
            {
                total[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
            } 
            else if(array1[i] != null)
            {
                total[i] = array1[i];
            }
            else if (array2[i] != null)
            {
                total[i] = array2[i];
            }
            else
            {
                total[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        return total;
    }
```

Problem is that I can't check and see if an int array is null. I read something about doing an:
    If(i < array1.Length)

but that does not seem to work either, it says it will always be true in my case.
Am I on the right track at all or is there some major flaw I'm missing? :)

Comment: Are we allowed to return the original array if the other one is null, or *must* we return a copy? And what should be returned if both are null? Where is this `15` coming from? Is that always going to be the length of an array if it isn't null?

Comment: Oh yes sorry forgot to add that. Basicly what I want to do is get an array with 15 int values, either arr1+arr2 or just arr1(if arr2 doesn't exist) or arr2(if arr1 doesn't exist) or just 0 if both arr1 and arr2 doesnt exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
    int[] ArrTotal(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        if (a == null || b == null) 
        {
            return (int[])(a ?? b).Clone();
        }
        int length = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
        int[] result = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            if (a.Length > i) sum += a[i];
            if (b.Length > i) sum += b[i];
            result[i] = sum;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @Xerion Note that this will give you a null reference exception if `a` or `b` is null. Your original spec seemed to indicate that was a possibility, but if this works for you then I guess it isn't?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Added null check

Comment: thnx, yeah I needed that. Still a novice so you're kind to remind me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to check lengths of both arrays before:

```
int length = (array1.Length < array2.Length ? array1.Length : array2.Length);
```

Then iterate and assign only to array indeces from 0 to length of the shorter array - 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    if (i < length)
        newArray[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
    else
        newArray[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int[] a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1 };
        int[] a2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3 };
        List<int> r = new List<int>();
        bool a1_longer = (a1.Length > a2.Length);
        int length_diff = Math.Abs(a1.Length - a2.Length);
        int length = (a1_longer ? a2.Length : a1.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) r.Add(a1[i] + a2[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < length_diff; i++) {
            r.Add(a1_longer ? a1[length + i] : a2[length+i]);
        }
        r.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Linq for it:

```
int[] ArrTotal(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(0, Math.Max(array1.Length,array2.Length))
        .Select((a, index) => a + 
            ((array1.Length > index) ? array1[index] : 0)+
            ((array2.Length > index) ? array2[index] : 0))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq you can do this (which will handle null arrays). You will need a `using System.Linq` at the top of the source code file:

```
int[] ArrTotal(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    if ((array1 == null) && (array2 == null))
        return new int[0]; // Zero length array - put some other number here if you need!
    else if (array1 == null)
        return (int[])array2.Clone(); // Result will just be a copy of the non-null array.
    else if (array2 == null)
        return (int[]) array1.Clone(); // Result will just be a copy of the non-null array.
    else
    {
        int skip = Math.Min(array1.Length, array2.Length);

        return Enumerable
            .Zip(array1, array2, (i1, i2) => i1 + i2)
            .Concat(array1.Skip(skip))
            .Concat(array2.Skip(skip))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```